# schedule sending out emails using mailapp.sendemail

Tags: javascript

I need to ask how to properly use the the `SetTimeOut()` function within the `mailapp.sendemail`.

```
var sendmail2 = date+1*3600000*24;
MailApp.sendEmail (userEmail, subject2, message2, {setTimeout:[sendmail2]});
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  W3Schools says 'The setTimeout() method calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds.'  That is not what you appear to be doing.  Please make your question clearer.

Comment: I want to be able to use the MailApp.sendEmail to send out a second email after a specified time period.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you be able to do this by

```
var delay = timePeriod;
MailApp.SendEmail(...email parameters...)
setTimeout(delay, function() { MailApp.SendEmail (...New mail parameters...) });
```

Comment: Cannot work, although no script errors...

function myFunction(e){

var userEmail = e.values[1];
var date = e.values[0];

var subject = "Optin";
var message = "Thank you, your eBook request was received ";
var DOC = DriveApp.getFileById("1-xxx");
var PDF = DOC.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
MailApp.sendEmail (userEmail, subject, message, {attachments:[PDF]});

var delay = date + 2*1000*60;

var subject2 = "Autoresponder Canned -2";
var message2 = "This is a test.";

setTimeout(delay, function() { MailApp.SendEmail (userEmail, subject2, message2) });
}

Comment: I think the timeout range might be too large.  2 minutes is a long time in a browser - It may have timed out the javascript by then.

Comment: Thank you, Brody. Seems, the only way to work around this, is to assign a new date value into a new cell in the spreadsheet.

Once this is done, script will be invoked to send 2nd email based on the new cell's date.